# How to disable spotlight for Alfred

Tags: spotlight, alfred, indexing

I use Alfred instead of spotlight but sometimes I accidentally press cmd + space( Spotlight Shortcut ) instead of double shift( Alfred Shortcut ). I want to disable Spotlight( shortcut + not run it in background as well )  so might not open it. Also, does Alfred use spotlight file indexing if `yes` then I might not want to disable that but if `no` I would like to disable that as well.

Answer (score 4):

In the "System Preferences" app select "Spotlight" from the top row. Now, uncheck the box titled "Spotlight search keyboard shortcut:"

I set the Alfred keyboard shortcut to <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>, which works a bit like Alfred on stock Yosemite machines.

If you want to keep the ability to search Spotlight with a keyboard shortcut, you could also change the shortcut using the popup menu to the right of the checkbox.

[image]

Comment: what about fileIndexing does Alfred use spotlight's fileIndexing ?

Comment: Yes it does. You are not turning off spotlight, just the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Disabling file indexing: http://osxdaily.com/2011/12/10/disable-or-enable-spotlight-in-mac-os-x-lion/