# How to disable spotlight for Alfred El Captain

Tags: spotlight, alfred

I have asked this question last year. In the link below.

[How to disable spotlight for Alfred](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177984/how-to-disable-spotlight-for-alfred)

But, since the settings now changed in El Captain the answer is not valid now. Please re-answer. I don't want to stop indexing. I just to disable spotlight and assign cmd+space to Alfred.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is almost the same as the previous answer you linked.

**Disable ⌘Space for Spotlight**:

- Go to **System Preferences > Spotlight**.
- In the lower left, click the button **Keyboard Shortcuts...** (this is the part that changed in El Capitan).
- Now in the keyboard shortcuts menu, deselect **Show Spotlight Search**.

[image]

Note that this does not disable Spotlight. Spotlight is just not accessible via ⌘Space anymore.

**Enable ⌘Space for Alfred**:

- In Alfred's Preferences choose the **General** tab.
- Set ⌘Space under **Alfred Hotkey** .